# How we will make a simple calculator just in php with one output textbox

Tags: php

Here is my form and i want to make a simple calculator in php using with one text box

```
<form action="calculator.php" method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="result">
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="one" value="1">
  <input type="button" name="two" value="2">
  <input type="button" name="three" value="3">
  <input type="button" name="four" value="4">
  <input type="button" name="five" value="5">
  <input type="button" name="six" value="6">
  <input type="button" name="seven" value="7">

  <input type="button" name="eight" value="8">
  <input type="button" name="nine" value="9">
  <input type="button" name="0" value="0">
  <input type="button" name="+" value="+">
  <input type="button" name="-" value="-">
  <input type="button" name="*" value="*">


</form>
```

Comment: Tagging mysql wasn't actually necessary.

Comment: what is in `calculator.php`? and what is the issue?

Comment: its my current page name

Comment: when i click on number then how they concatenate and how they perform maths opertaion

Comment: Pleas include the PHP logic inside your question.

Comment: try ajax for your calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to use some javascript, get the values and append to the text box

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmCalc input:button").on("click", function() {
        var par = $(this).val();            
        $("#result").val($("#result").val() + par);
    });
});
</script>
<form action="calculator.php" id="frmCalc" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="result" id="result">
<br>
<input type="button" name="one" value="1">
<input type="button" name="two" value="2">
<input type="button" name="three" value="3">
<input type="button" name="four" value="4">
<input type="button" name="five" value="5">
<input type="button" name="six" value="6">
<input type="button" name="seven" value="7">

<input type="button" name="eight" value="8">
<input type="button" name="nine" value="9">
<input type="button" name="0" value="0">
<input type="button" name="+" value="+">
<input type="button" name="-" value="-">
<input type="button" name="*" value="*">
</form>
```

Comment: That's using Javascript, not PHP. Also, you haven't implemented any of the operators.

Comment: If you modify the jquery, you can do the operations instantly when click on '='

Comment: sir i have no more knowledge about jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you send your request to calculator.php like this, you can't tell the difference between the numbers you pressed first.

So first of all you need to put those numbers into a text field - maybe with javascript? - and then you can transmit the form to calculator.php and do the math. If you only got one textfield, you can simply split the string you will get and search for your operations.